# Replace specific tags in html content with new values using preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I'm sorry if there are already some posts with the same problem, however, I tried everything and I still can't find what seems to be the problem with my code.

So what I want is to replace the src attribute content with my own. For example, say I have an HTML document like this:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <img src="123">
    <p>
        <img src="abc123">
    </p>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <img src="w?ijais,cn,a;;sqikxiasassaswxzdvfrfr...">
</div>
```

I want to search for every image tag, strip the src value, do some parsing, and then replace it with another value. Here's my PHP code with a random logic for simplicity sake:

```
//The HTML content
$content = "<div><p>Hello</p>...";

//A number I want to use to modify the src values
$id = 9;

//Starts with <img src=" and ends with "/> with any number of characters in the middle
//I escape the double quotes: \"
$pattern = "/<img src=\"(.*)\">/";

//Calling preg_replace_callback
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use($id){
    changeImage($matches[0], $id);
}, $content);

echo $result;
```

---

```
//changeImage function
public function changeImage($image, $id){
    //Stripping the src value
    $img = str_replace("<img src=\"", "", $image);
    $img = str_replace("\">", "", $img);
    //Modifying the src value
    $img = $id . "-" . $img[0] . $img[1];
    //Putting back the tags
    $img = "<img src=\"$img\">";
    return $img;
}
```

The result should be:

```
 <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <img src="9-12">
    <p>
        <img src="9-ab">
    </p>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <img src="9-w?">
</div>
```

Here's what I get:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>

    <p>
    
    </p>
    <h1>Title</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: what part of this is not working

Comment: @Berto99 The resulting html content is wrong. Instead of replacing the img tags with the new values, it replaces them with empty strings.

Comment: @I've updated my question and included the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the string that you want to replace with, so from this:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use($id){
    changeImage($matches[0], $id);
}, $content);
```

to this:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use($id){
    return changeImage($matches[0], $id);
}, $content);
```

EDIT: is suggested to use `/<img[^>]*>/` as REGEX to match the `img` tag

Comment: While that seemed to solve my initial problem, when I have HTML content that's not structured, I get another problem. Example:
    $content = "<div><p>Hello</p><img src=\"123\"><p><img src=\"abc123\"></p><h1>Title</h1><img src=\"w?ijais,cn,a;;sqikxiasassaswxzdvfrfr...\"></div>";

This returns:
<div>
    <p>Hello</p><img src="9-12"></div>

Comment: I mean that it's just a long continuous string. There are no newlines or anything.

Comment: @RandomBeginner then there is a problem on the regex, look on the internet and you will find a lot of those already tested and working fine

Comment: Thank you. Though I already looked, and I can't seem to find an issue with my Regex. Thanks.

Comment: @RandomBeginner try this regex `/<img[^>]*>/`

Comment: @RandomBeginner sure, the `<img` is just the opening tag which will match the actual characters case insensitive, then there is `[^>]` which means `[...]*`-> something inside this how many times you want, and inside there is `^>` where the first character is the "negation" operator, and then `>` that is the closing tag, so it is `<img[everything that is not ">"]how many times you want`... you can read more here https://regex101.com/r/yoGCvT/1 in the menu on the right

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, will there be any problem if the src attribute contains ">" by any chance?

Comment: @RandomBeginner yes might happens, but better than this you can't do, just thing if inside the tag there are others attribute like `data-id` or style ecc ecc... the other way is to use a web scraper

Comment: @RandomBeginner no problem, feel free to leave an upvote, and if you think this solves your problem, to mark the answer as correct